# Clarification regarding (deepTools) bamCoverage output

Tags: rna-seq, deeptools

Im using bamCoverage on a file and ive set the bin size to 1 but also normalizing using RPKM for defined regions using a bedgraph file.  The output from bamCoverage however is in binned segments each with a (RPKM) score.  Am I correct in interpreting then that

1 - the output bedgraph tells me the (total) RPKM score for that particular bin?

2 - to get the total RPKM score for the region defined in the bedgraph I need to sum all the RPKM scores given for that particular region?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, RPKM includes a "normalization" by unit of length, so it does not make sense to sum these values along a region. A weighted average makes more sense (were the weights would be the bin widths).

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. The total RPKM for the region in the bedgraph file is the value already present in the bedgraph file. If you want to estimate the RPKM for a larger region composed of multiple bins then you can average the per-bin RPKM values. Note that adjacent bins with the same value are merged by deepTools, so you will need to account for this.

Note that RPKM is NOT a robust normalization and that I should remove it from deepTools so people stop using it.

Comment: @OP If you want a more robust normalization I suggest (disclaimer, I am the author of the post) https://www.biostars.org/p/413626/#414440